# Why does IDLE keep saying my print function is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.6

import math

```
radius = int(input(' Can I please get the radius of your circle ')
print(math.pi * radius**2 )
```

That's my code, I'm super new to programming and I just don't get it

Thank you so much, I got it

Comment: What's the exact error?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a parenthesis to match up with the `int` function:

```
radius = int(input(' Can I please get the radius of your circle ')) #<-right here
print(math.pi * radius**2 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing bracket in the first line:

```
radius = int(input(' Can I please get the radius of your circle '))  
#                                      ---------------------------^
```